# Substitution of image with absolute path in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I am trying to create a substitute that can go across the different `toctree`s.
in `index.rst`:

```
.. |logo| image:: _images/logo.jpg

EXAMPLE TITLE
==============
.. toctree::
   :glob:
   
   subfolder/subindex.rst
```

and in `subfolder/subindex.rst`:

```
THE LOGO
=========
|logo|
```

This did however not work. I tried using the epilog/prolog in `conf.py:

```py
rst_epilog = """
.. |logo| image:: _images/logo.jpg
"""
```

I also tried to create a `global.rst` in the same folder as `index.rst` and include it in both (`.. include:: global.rst`), but the path for `subfolder/subindex.rst` became a relative path, complaining that it could not find the include in `subfolder/global.rst`

How would one achieve a(n) (elegant) "global" substitution across `.rst` files?

Comment: epilog/prolog support only string replacement, not interpretation. Honestly, it is easier to just do `.. image:: /_images/logo.jpg` (note the root-relative path) wherever you need it, and not try to fiddle around with includes or replacements.

Comment: I suspect you are correct, but I asked the question to make sure.
It's going to be a pain since there are so many subfolders with `rst` files and it would be so nice to have the global path to include and images.

Comment: There is no "global path", but there is a root-relative path. Use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already have a folder named **images** in your directory. Therefore, you should not point directly to the **_images** folder created by the sphinx compiler.

As a result, you must have the following filer:

**index.rst**

```
EXAMPLE TITLE
==============

.. toctree::
   :glob: 

   subfolder/subindex.rst
```

**subfolder/subindex.rst**

```
THE LOGO
=========
|logo|
```

**conf.py**

```
rst_prolog += '''
.. |logo| image:: /images/apluslogo.png
'''
```

Comment: I had my own folder which I called `_images` because I thought it was Sphinx standard. However, your answer gave me what I did wrong. I did:

 ```rst_epilog = """ .. |logo| image:: _images/logo.jpg"""
``` 
However, I should do:
```rst_epilog = """ .. |logo| image:: /_images/logo.jpg """
```